# Setting frame to Date picker in iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uidatepicker

I am able to set date picker frame from Storyboard. But I am not able to set the frame programatically. I would like to no why `datePicker.frame` is not working even though `setFrame:` functionality is not deprecated in iOS7. Also please provide a way to set date picker frame programatically. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please define frame first and Use [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:]

Comment: CGRect frame = CGRectMake(225, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 125);
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda I tried that already..but not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already added UIDatePicker to .nib or .storyboard file and would like to update frame programatically, then you can update frame inside viewDidLayoutSubviews method in your view controller. I just tried to update frame and it worked on iOS 7.0

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 300, 162);
}
```

If want to add a date picker programatically in view controller then you can try creating a date picker in viewDidLoad method and add it to subview.

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 300, 162)];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```