# UIDatePicker in UITableViewCell cannot be resized (height)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uidatepicker

This might be a totally stupid question, but I'm trying to follow the DateCell example in the WWDC sample code to have a date picker in the UITableViewCell.

In the Apple example, the height is `216` and fits the entire `UITableViewCell` that also has a height of `216`.

In my own storyboard, I manually set the height of the `UITableViewCell` to `216` & then I tried adding a `UIDatePicker` to the `UITableViewCell`.
I am neither able to set the height by dragging the `UITableViewCell` nor enter the height.

[image]

[image]

Is there a checkbox or setting I am missing somewhere?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't resize the `UIDatePicker` from the xib.
You can programmatically resize it though but then again only upto a certain minimum height.

Check out the following *similar* questions:

- [iOS 7 UIDatePicker height inconsistency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970679/ios-7-uidatepicker-height-inconsistency)
- [Setting frame to Date picker in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513007/setting-frame-to-date-picker-in-ios7)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click on Your xib or Storyboard
2. Select "Open As" option
3. Select "Source Code" option
4. Now, Search "datePicker" and change frame of Date Picker

Comment: For step 1, are you talking about right clicking on the storyboard in Finder?  I don't have the ability to Open as Option.

Comment: No if you are using storybord  Right click on your ViewControler's interface builder in xcode..